# Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/20/i386

Tags: fedora, yum

I installed Fedora 20 using the liveOS.

While taking the updates I am getting the following result:

```
[root@localhost bioinfo]# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/20/i386. Please verify its path and try again
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 25):

This problem seems to come using secure `https`. Go in `/etc/yum.repository.d` and replace all `https` with `http` in different `.repo` files.

Comment: fwiw, confirmed on fedora 17

Comment: -- confirmed with Fedora 15

Comment: Weird as https is the default... Date and time correct (lol and not on a lenovo laptop).

Comment: This worked for me: ls /etc/yum.repository.d/*.repo | xargs sed -i 's/https:/http:/g'

Answer (score 8):

It is possible that your `ca-certificates` are in need of an update or corrupt.

Try:

```
# yum update ca-certificates
```

If that doesn't offer to update the package, then reinstall:

```
# yum reinstall ca-certificates
```

If that fails, it could be that the server you are connected to has updated it's certificates (maybe from a new vendor) and that the certificate chain and/or root certificate isn't in the `ca-certificates` package yet.  The certificates in this package are chosen by the Mozilla Foundation.

If this is the case, then @Saturn's answer should hopefully help.

Answer (score 7):

I modded up the other two answers, they're both helpful ... GarethTheRed has got the real answer. I ran into the same problem after doing a version upgrade and my `ca-certificates` was out of date.

However, to be able to update `ca-certificates`, you first have to be able to actually use `yum`. I suggest:

1. Go to `/etc/yum.repos.d`
2. Edit `fedora.repo` and `fedora-updates.repo`. In both files, uncomment the `baseurl` line that uses plain `http` and comment out the `metalink` url that uses `https`.
3. Do `yum update ca-certificates` or `yum reinstall ca-certificates` (as in Gareth's answer).
4. Undo the changes from step 2 so that you will go back to using both `https` and the metalink redirect.
5. All done, test `yum` and it should work again.

Comment: The problem is that, somewhere between versions 21 and 23, the list of supported https supported protocols changed, and now for those older versions, it is no longer possible to have the updated certificates.  Therefore, at least for versions 20 and below, Saturn's answer is the only working solution. (regarding the statement "GarethTheRed has got the real answer.")

Answer (score 0):

inaddition to above mensioned , we have to do edit the web links which are not present.
like
replace the lines in /etc/yum.repo.d/* with 'baseurl=http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux' with 'baseurl=http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux'
It worked for me.
Try it out.
LOL....

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Fedora is 23, there are still updates for 22. Fedora 20 is long, long past end of life. No wonder there are no updates anymore.